# Road bike and mountain bike shoes

Tags: road-bike, road, spd

I have a road bike with Look pedals that I would like to ride with SPD pedals, are they any adapters to the cleats that would allow me to do it?

Comment: Perhaps you'd rather replace them with SPD pedals?

Comment: If your shoes can take a two-bolt cleat, just change the cleats.  If you want to use the shoes on two different bikes, it will be best to have a second pair of shoes.   Otherwise an adapter plate between 2/3 holes is your best plan.

Comment: Change the Look pedals to SPD pedals. You may get quite inexpensive single sided SPD pedals that almost look like road pedals and that won't 'disfigure' a road bike.

Answer (score 1):

I take your question to mean you have road style 3 bolt cleat shoes, but want to use them with Shimano SPD type pedals that need a 2 bolt cleat. You are looking for a way to attach 2 bolt SPD cleats to the 3 bolt shoes.

Another way of putting it is you need a Shimano SPD to SPD-R adapter (SPD-R (road) cleats use 3 bolt attachment).

Yes, there are adapters available. Specific product recommendations or shopping help are off topic here so I wont link to a specific product, but try Googling 'Shimano SPD SPD-R adapter'.